# area of a triangle is a prime number

Tags: prime-numbers

Using six consecutive primes to create the points (59,61), (67,71), and (73,79) as vertices of a triangle with an area of just 2, the first prime of six is 59.  Will the area ever again
be 2?  Can the area ever be an odd prime?

Comment: If we take the least prime to be $2$, is not the area $3$?  First example I tried.

Comment: What is the first prime of six consecutive ones that gave you a triangle with prime area 3?  Did you find another triangle with area TWO?

Comment: I believe I said, the least prime was $2$.  I  did not search systematically.  You asked if the area could be an odd prime.  Barring error, my example (again, the first I tried) proves it can.

Comment: Note that it is conjectured that "possible" prime combinations - ie those not barred by obvious congruence problems - so $p, p+2, p+8, p+12, p+14, p+20$ as here - will appear infinitely often, and this will simply translate the same triangle many times. (The test is that for any prime $p$ they don't cover every congruence class modulo $p$).

Comment: Should say:  it's not obvious to me that the area is always an integer.  It's clear that  twice the area is an integer, but I don't immediately see why half integers are impossible.  A quick search shows that the area is generally even (the reason for which is also not clear to me).

Comment: Starting with the prime $739$ gives area $2$.  The vertices being $(739, 743),\,
(751 ,757),\,
(761, 769)$.

Comment: @lulu  In the numerator of that formula, each term has a factor which is the difference of two odd primes.  That makes the numerator even.

Comment: I agree that  first prime 2  will give area 3, but 2 is an even prime.  What about if all six are odd primes--any areas that are also primes?  If you think the area is not always an integer, then find examples.  That the area is generally even gives you the reason why I posed the question.  You stated that the prime gaps will be 2,  6, 4, 2, 6 and that they will occur infinitely often.  Can there be a different collection of gaps to also give area 2?

Comment: @B.Goddard  Ah, good point. Thanks.

Comment: Our comments crossed.  Note that your example has prime gaps of 4. 8, 6, 4, 8 which differs from the gaps I sent.

Comment: The slopes of the sides given by  the triangle with starting prime 739 differs from the slopes of the sides given by triangle with starting number 59.  One wonders just how many differently  shaped triangles will give areas of 2.

Comment: It could happen that the area is a semiprime: divide by 2 to see how large the prime is.

Comment: Early results at  http://oeis.org/history?seq=A308649